# Why are my title´s and image´s changing all the time I click on my project?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Every time I click on my button, a new controller is shown with a navigation bar. But unfortunately the images and titles change their order and duplicate themselves..

The order should be firm.

Comment: Dictionaries have no order.

Comment: Oh damn... I totally forgot about the dictionaries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a struct with the your table, icon and controller name as properties and store that struct in an array

```
struct Action {
    let label: String
    let control: String
    let icon: String
}

let actions = [Action(label: "Pläne", control: "PlansViewController2", icon: "plancorrection"), 
               Action(label: "Dokumentationen", control: "DocumentationListViewCtrl", icon: "list"), ...]
```

and then get all values needed from the same array

```
cell.titelLabel.text = actions[row].label
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: actions[row].icon)
cell.imageView.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
```

To get the correct identifier for the view controller

```
if let action = actions.first(where: {$0.label == pnc}) {
    let newController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: action.control)
} else {
    //some error handling here
}
```

Comment: How do I have to change the showList() method so that it works correctly? Now I get the images but navigation is still random

Comment: @Preefix I have updated my answer with a suggested solution

Comment: Its still random.. Where do I have to put "action" ? I´m very confused right now sorry

Comment: @Preefix, Sorry, I forgot to change one part. Answer updated.